# Tooltip in seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a test data frame here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4],
                   'y': [1,4,9,16],
            'z' : ['A','B','C','D']})
```

This will look as

```
   x   y  z
0  1   1  A
1  2   4  B
2  3   9  C
3  4  16  D
```

Now I want to do a `seaborn` scatter plot and put tool tips using the `z` column. Here is my `seaborn` scatter plot code

```
g = sns.regplot(x=df["x"],
                y=df["y"], 
            fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={'s':30},
            color='red')

g.set_title('My Plot')

fig = g.get_figure()

fig.savefig('myplot.png')
```

And here is the figure.
[image]

Now when I hover over the data point, I want the value of column `z` to be displayed for that row. How would I do that ?

Comment: Can this be done in base `matplotlib` without using `seaborn` ?

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? The referenced answers refer only to matplotlib, this question here is about seaborn.